# ExecutorService FixedThreadPool as a shared parameter not running in parallel

Tags: java, java-8, threadpool

I am trying to use fixed thread pool in Java 8 which works perfect as long as it stays within the same function. Once I try sharing the executor as a parameter, it never runs in parallel.

This works great:

```

````
public static void test2() {

ExecutorService executor =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
try {
    CompletionService<Integer> myCompletionService = 
               new ExecutorCompletionService<Integer>(executor);


    myCompletionService.submit(()-> {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            return 123;
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("task interrupted", e);
        }
    });


    CompletionService<Integer> myCompletionService2 = 
               new ExecutorCompletionService<Integer>(executor);
    myCompletionService2.submit(()-> {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            return 654;
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("task interrupted", e);
        }
    });

    Future<Integer> myFuture = myCompletionService.take();
    Integer x = myFuture.get();
    System.out.println("Result = " + x);

    Future<Integer> myFuture2 = myCompletionService2.take();
    Integer y = myFuture2.get();
    System.out.println("Result = " + y);

    executor.shutdown();
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
}
```
````

But once I move these into three functions like:

```

```
static Integer t1(ExecutorService executor) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    CompletionService<Integer> myCompletionService = 
               new ExecutorCompletionService<Integer>(executor);


    myCompletionService.submit(()-> {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            return 123;
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("task interrupted", e);
        }
    });
    Future<Integer> myFuture = myCompletionService.take();
    return myFuture.get();
}

static Integer t2(ExecutorService executor) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    CompletionService<Integer> myCompletionService2 = 
               new ExecutorCompletionService<Integer>(executor);


    myCompletionService2.submit(()-> {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            return 456;
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("task interrupted", e);
        }
    });
    Future<Integer> myFuture2 = myCompletionService2.take();
    return myFuture2.get();
}

static void test3() {
    ExecutorService executor =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    try {
        Integer x = t1(executor);
        Integer y = t2(executor);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

```
Now test3 will take 10 seconds, where I expected it to be the same as the top one which should take 5 seconds if things are running in parallel.,

Comment: The entire use of `CompletionService` is obsolete here. You can call `submit` directly on the `ExecutorService` and it returns the `Future`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In t1 after submitting you are calling get() and get blocked, so you exit from t1 only when first task is finished (after 5 secs).

In first example you submit both tasks so they starting executing in separate threads and then only call get() to block and wait for result.